# Making labels invisible after some time NetBeans

Tags: java, timer, thread-sleep

I am making a program in which I am supposed to make visibility of labels false after, say, 1 sec intervals
The program is pretty long and complex to quote so I am explaining it. I have an array of labels and each time a label is setVisible(false), slp() method is executed.

```
public void slp() 
{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
}
```

But I am facing a problem.  The method just increases the time of execution of thread and all the labels become invisible together at last. I need animation effect, and that is not coming.
What would be a good solution to my problem? Can a timer serve me?

Comment: you need to run the 1-sec wait in a new thread.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, your method `slp` should probably take a `JLabel` as argument, so you can modify the visibility of a specific label. Otherwise, the method would not know which label to hide.

Second, in order not to block the main thread (or whatever thread that class `slp()`), the `Thread.sleep(1000)` should be run in its own thread. That's why the code below uses `new Thread(....).start();` to create a new thread that will do the actual work.

Third, as the waiting now is in a separate thread, changing the labels visibility must be done again on the Swing Events thread. For this, we use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) where we then set the label's visibility.

All together, the code could look like this:

```
public void slp(JLabel label) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    label.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The code could be further "cleaned up" by using lambda-expressions as available since Java 8:

```
public void slp(JLabel label) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> label.setVisible(false));
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I used the first code except that I didn't take the label as a parameter. It was global so I directly referred to it. But now, it seems as if it didn't even enter slp().

Comment: the code above will hide a label after 1 second. If it is not working for you, something else must be wrong in your code. Please post a [mcve] so that we can help you instead of guessing.